# Webpack-dev-server doesn't generate source maps

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), but can't figure out how to generate or where find source maps for transpiled files. I tried `eval-source-map`, `inline-source-map`, `source-map`.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/script/index.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: "bundle.js.map",
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   
                test: /\.js[x]?$/, 
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'jsx', 'babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/ 
              },
              {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap' ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'less?sourceMap' ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [ 'style', 'css']
              },
              { test: /\.woff$/,   loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
              { test: /\.woff2$/,   loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2" },
              { test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/,    loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BowerWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    externals: {
        //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
        //but get it from a global 'React' variable
        'react': 'React'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
    "name": "Won",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Internal evidence application",
    "main": "index.jsx",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
        "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090"
    },
    "author": "And",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^5.8.23",
        "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.7.3",
        "bootstrap-table": "^1.8.1",
        "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.8",
        "colresizable": "^1.5.2",
        "css-loader": "^0.16.0",
        "events": "^1.0.2",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
        "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
        "flux": "^2.1.1",
        "http-server": "^0.8.0",
        "jquery": "^2.1.4",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
        "json-markup": "^0.1.6",
        "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
        "less": "^2.5.1",
        "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "^3.10.1",
        "node-sass": "^3.2.0",
        "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
        "path": "^0.11.14",
        "react": "^0.13.3",
        "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
        "sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.12.3",
        "svg-sprite-loader": "0.0.2",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
        "webpack": "^1.12.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.1"
    }
}
```

edit://

After all this [webpack.config.js](http://pastebin.com/MH7WHGKG) and this [package.json](http://pastebin.com/HwJCS4R3) works for me.

edit2://

Now I use [this webpack config](http://andrejgajdos.com/setting-up-webpack-for-es6-react-sass-and-bootstrap/)

Comment: Note that given you are using Babel, you skip jsx-loader. So just `['hot-loader', 'babel']` is enough. Babel supports JSX by default.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm running into the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Pathsofdesign for me it works now, but I don't know what I changed. If you want, I can send you my webpack.config and package.json.

Comment: @Matt I certainly would upvote an answer that has your updated webpack.config and package.json. :-)

Comment: @GabrielKunkel please see my edited question. There is my webpack.config and package.json which works for me

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks. Duh. :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `webpack -d`

The `d` flag stands for development shortcut and it enables all of your developer tools such as source maps.

Comment: Webpack generates source maps for scss files, but not for jsx files. Please see my edited post, I attached my package.json

Comment: @CpILL it worked for me, I ran `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -d --port 10141 --content-base build`

Comment: @ryeguy on webpack 2?

Comment: @CpILL No, I'm running webpack 1.13.3 and webpack-dev-server 1.16.2

Answer (score 44):

**Use `webpack-dev-server -d`**

- `-d` is shorthand for `--debug --devtool source-map --output-pathinfo`.
- `output-pathinfo` adds comments to the generated bundle that explain what module/files are included in what places. So in the generated code, the comment is added to this line of code: `require(/* ./test */23)` which says that `23` is pointing to the `test` module. This is mostly helpful when you're looking at the code Webpack has generated, and not so much when stepping through the debugger. I got this example [from this relevant bit of documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-pathinfo).
- This all works because `webpack-dev-server` accepts all the same flags as `webpack`.
- [See this section in the docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli) for details.

### Tips & gotchas

- `--content-base` - by default the dev server will serve files in the directory you run the command in. If your build files are in `build/`, you need to specify `--content-base build/` so the dev server will serve up files in the `build` directory
- `--inline` - auto-reload whenever you save a file with some changes!

Comment: what does the output-pathinfo actually do?

Comment: @angrykiwi updated my answer, thanks! Also, great name btw ;)

Answer (score 6):

Add `{devtool:"source-map"}` to your **webpack.config.js**

See more [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i found that in my webpack config it was `cheap-module-eval-source-map` and it didn't worked, i tried couple other options from this link and it works great now with `eval-source-map`

Comment: I'm also having issues with `cheap-module-eval-source-map`. Other types work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please add in you webpack.config.js file the following`

> devtool: "#inline-source-map",

You can find clear information about it from the site of webpack` https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Also please find attached screenshot of sourcemap part, from webpack site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All I did is change:

```
// package.json
{
    ...
    **from** "dev:serve": "webpack-dev-server",
    **to** "dev:serve": "webpack-dev-server -d",
    ...
}
```

Equivalent to: `$ webpack-dev-server -d`

Now I can utilize `Ctrl + p` in Chrome and I see my ES6 syntax to set breakpoints on.

Info

```
$ webpack-dev-server --version
webpack-dev-server 2.9.7
webpack 3.10.0
```